# Fade Out Splash Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a fade out on the splash page I've created which blends into the main page of my site. My site is: http://www.simonsamuel.com/

The jQuery code I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#splash").click(function() {
        $("#splash").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
#splash {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgbox.com/Al4c3tZ5.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    top: -60px; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

I've tried a number of different codes but I can't find the one that works with my site. And just out of curiosity, I'd like to know if it's possible to alter the webpage title with jQuery? I want to make the title bar uppercase font.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code and yes, you can alter the web page title with jQuery. Folks may not be willing to visit an external link and dig through your source to find out what #splash is and how it is setup. One last thing, enclose your code in a document ready handler: $(document).ready(function() {...yourcode here...});

Comment: your jquery code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/ do you load the jquery library?

Comment: Actually the jQuery code that you have above is NOT in your web page. Are you loading that script?

Comment: Yeah, I put the jQuery code into the custom HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a fiddle to demonstrate the basics - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/nBdkU/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#splash').css('opacity', '0.5'); // doing this with jQuery for ease

    // here are the basics, just like your existing code
    $("#splash").click(function () {
        $("#splash").fadeOut("slow"); // you could also use $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Watching the console when loading your page I get a syntax error that points to the same problems that @Puzzle84 points out -

```
<script type="text/javascript"><br />
$(document).ready(function() {<br />
$('#splash').click(function() {<br />
    $('#splash').fadeOut(2000);<br />
  });<br />
</script>
```

All of these lines breaks need to be removed. Then, as he pointed out, you need another set of closing brackets ( **});** ) before the closing script tag. When I then click on the splash element it disappears and your site is shown. If you have things that you're trying to show in the splash element you'll just have to get the CSS positioning right for those.

There are also other errors pointed out in the console (Cargo.View.Main is not defined)

For the title bit you can either do some pure JavaScript or a little jQuery -

```
document.title = 'the page title'; // changes the title
document.title.toUpperCase(); // sets title to upper case

$(document).attr('title', 'the page title'); // changes the title
$(document).attr('title').toUpperCase(); // sets to upper case
```

Comment: I tried the codes you have provided the opacity code works but the fade code doesn't work. When I put in the code there isn't "<br />" placed in. I think the site is placing this in automatically. And the title code also doesn't work either.

Comment: If the site is placing it in there automatically (and getting rid of curly braces) then there is a problem because it is causing a syntax error that causes the jQuery to fail. Perhaps you need to talk to the site admin?

Comment: @Simon I now see a truckload of backslashes in the code, like someone is trying to escape characters for something. Also - where is jQuery loaded in the source? I cannot locate it. None of your jQuery code is working though, and I wonder if it isn't because jQuery is not loaded?

Comment: I'm a beginner at jQuery, how do I load it?

I've messaged the site admin about it all so they should hopefully get back to me. However the first code for the splash opacity worked and so does the title page code.

I have also found that when I click onto another page and click back to the previous page the jQuery codes are inactive and are dismissed. I'm not sure why this is happening.

I found this article: http://support.cargocollective.com/customer/portal/questions/1148181

Might be useful as to why it's not working.

Comment: Unfortunately that support question isn't of much use here because you're not dealing with dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 1):

When i look at your source code i see this:

```
<br />
$(document).ready(function() {<br />
    $('#splash').click(function() {<br />
        $('#splash').fadeOut(2000);<br />
    });<br />
```

why is there linebreaks in that code?
that's html code.

besides that your code is incomplete

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#splash').click(function() {
       $('#splash').fadeOut(2000);
    }); // forgot these
}); // or these
```

Comment: I tried changing it around and it still doesn't work, I'm hosting on Cargo Collective. I'm not sure why I'm experiencing this problem

Comment: @Simon As I look at the code this morning I do not see these changes. Are you sure you uploaded them?